# Boost message_queue: just the constructor lets me configure it, no other member functions available

Tags: c++, boost, constructor, initialization, message-queue

This is a classic Boost message_queue example:

```
#include <boost/interprocess/ipc/message_queue.hpp>
using namespace boost::interprocess;
struct Data { ... };

int main() {
    Data data1;

    message_queue::remove("message_queue");

    message_queue mq(create_only, "message_queue", 100, sizeof(Data));

    mq.send(&data1, sizeof(Data), 0);
}
```

Now I would like to put the `mq` message_queue object inside a class as a member variable, with the lifetime of this class' object:

```
#include <boost/interprocess/ipc/message_queue.hpp>
using namespace boost::interprocess;

struct Data { ... };

class DataManager 
{
    message_queue mq;

public:
    DataManager() 
       : mq(create_only, "message_queue", 100, sizeof(Data))      // ok
    {
        mq.Open(create_only, "message_queue", 100, sizeof(Data));   // Open does not exist
    }
};
```

It seems I can only initialise the `mq` object in the member initialisation list, since `message_queue` does not provide the member functions to set its parameters at a later time.

Am I wrong? Is there another way to do it?

I would like to be able, e.g., to let an object use a message queue whose name is passed as a parameter to one of its member functions.

Thank you.

Comment: It seems you indeed can't set the parameters later, but how does this relate to your requirement?

Comment: Let's say I want my object to use a message queue which can change later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this :

```
class QueueManager
{
  boost::scoped_ptr<message_queue> mq;

  // ctor
  QueueManager(string msgqname) 
  {
      mq.reset(new message_queue(create_only, msgqname, 100, sizeof(Data));
  }
};
```

Just to give you an idea that at least some parameters can be passed to class constructor.
Since message queue uses shared memory underneath, I think most parameters can not be changed after construction.

Comment: I wanted to create the message_queue on demand, in a normal member function, not in the constructor. Using a scoped_ptr as you did seems to work in my case. Thank you!